# iOS fabric daily new user almost 0 recently

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Crashlytics works, I can receive errors and events everyday.
The daily new user count for Android is normal, about 20K, but for iOS, the count is 0~5 for these months. The sdk is updated to the latest. 
It worked well from 2016 until months before with nothing changed.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: The app bundle id is net.yeelink.MiLamp, could any staff help to check? Nothing has been changed, except the ProvisioningStyle changed from Automatic to Manual.